# does the series converge absolutely?

Tags: sequences-and-series

could somebody help me to answer and understand the following question:

does the series converges absulutely? $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{n!}$$

I´m not sure about the "absolut" reference. Generally I would say in converges to $0$ but I`m not really sure.

THX

Comment: Absolute convergence simply means that $$\sum_{n}|a_n|<\infty$$
Where $|\cdot|$ is the absolute value. Now simply solve for your given series
\\
\\
PS: keep in mind that if a series converges absolutely $\rightarrow$ the series converges. Whereas the other direction is NOT always true

Comment: Are you familiar with $e^{x}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{n}}{n!}$?
For convergence of the series take $x=-1$, for absolute convergence
of the series take $x=1$.

Comment: Absolutely! :-)

Comment: @drhab sorry but I´m not familier with that notation

Comment: Well, okay. Don't bother. It will probably come later.

Comment: the series converges absulutely at $0$ then, when taking $x=1$? Oke thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, the series does not converge to $0$. The series $\frac{-1^{n}}{n!}$ does converge to $0$, however the infinite sum does not. As you may know, the infinite sum is defined as a limit of partial sums:
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n = \lim_{N \rightarrow \infty}\sum_{n=0}^{N} a_n.
$$
If you look at these partial sums, $S_N = \sum_{n=0}^{N} a_n$, you can see they do not converge towards $0$. If you look at the first couple of values, you get:

```
1.0
0.0
0.5
0.333333333333
0.375
0.366666666667
0.368055555556
0.367857142857
0.367881944444
0.367879188713
```

The series looks like it converges to something other than $0$, and indeed it does. If you just want to prove that the series converges, you can use the ratio test described [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test). It tells you that the series converges if the limit

$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}|
$$
is less than $1$. In your case, $a_n = \frac{-1^{n}}{n!}$, giving you $|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}| = \frac{n!}{(n+1)!}=\frac{1}{n}$, the limit of this is $0<1$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$, therefore, the series converges.

For further analysis, it's good to have some knowledge of the Taylor series. If you know that the series

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!}$$ converges and is equal to $e^x$ for ALL $x\in\mathbb R$ and you substitute $x=-1$, you get that the sum
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{n!}$$
converges and is equal to $e^{-1}$

Comment: this sound plausible :) thx

Comment: I added information on how to actually calculate what the sum is.

Answer (score 1):

Use @drhab's nice points or use [Alternating series test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test). Moreover we can see that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}n^2|a_n|<\infty$$ so according to [Comparison test](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/SeriesCompTest.aspx) the $\sum|a_n|$ can be again converges.

Comment: @amWhy: Thank you very much my dear. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what example B.S have when saying according to comparison test...

I would love to see this as $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{n!}\leq\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{n^2}$$

P.S : I am not saying that $n! \geq n^2$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$